# Gatsby and Graphql - How to filter allMarkdownRemark by folder

Tags: reactjs, regex, graphql, gatsby, remarkjs

I'm using Gatsby and MarkdownRemark.

I want to query the markdown files and then filter them down to the files contained within a sub-directory. My folder structure looks like this:

```
- src
 - pages
   -index.md
   -about.md
   - team
    - team_member_1.md
    - team_member_2.md
    - team_member_3.md
```

So far I can query all the markdown pages in the directory but I'm having trouble trying to filter down path. There must be a way to do it with a graphQL query.

Instead what I do is map all the results and then check if the slug string includes 'team' this tells me that its in the 'team' folder. And then it makes the component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import TeamMember from '../components/TeamMember.js'
const Team = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields{
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              name
              position
              image
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <div>
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map( (item, index) => {
        if(item.node.fields.slug.includes('team')){
          return <TeamMember key={`team_member_${index}`}{...item.node.frontmatter}/>
        }
      } )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Team
```

This works fine. But I thought the whole point of graphQl is to query and filter to return the exact data I need. Instead I'm back at writing my own filter code in javascript:

```
if(item.node.fields.slug.includes('team'))
```

Is there a Gatsby plugin or a way to filter a query to contain items in a folder?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at the [gatsby graphql reference for filter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#filter) and make sure you are using graphiql to explore what is available within your schema.

```
query MyQuery {
  allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/(team)/"  }}) {
    nodes {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ksav, This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be a way to do it. I'm going to read through that filter documentation that you linked. I was having trouble articulating my searches to find this. Thanks.

Comment: For new people, and since no one here has mentioned it: filtering with `regex` and `fileAbsolutePath` is really, really slow. So if you can help it, filter with `eq` and `frontmatter` instead. My build times went from 11–12 minutes down to 3–4 minutes after changing. Read more about it [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/#performance).

Answer (score 2):

@ksav's answer works but it is important to note that `regex: "/(team)/"` also matches `C:\user\gatsby\src\team2\other.md`.

So I recommend using `allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/(/team/)/"  }}) {` instead.